# Cameo Report Wizard Custom Tool

Tags: java, catia, vtl

When attempting the tutorial tool install the tool loads into the system and does not import into the vtl template. Does anyone know if there are any steps missing from the documentation?
https://docs.nomagic.com/pages/viewpage.action?mobileBypass=true&spaceKey=MD190&title=Installing+custom+tool
https://docs.nomagic.com/pages/viewpage.action?mobileBypass=true&spaceKey=MD190&title=Importing+custom+tool+to+template

I verified that the file pulled into the jar was a .class file with the corresponding package, and the import matches the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

So the documentation is correct, it was a problem with environment configuration